# Unable to update the element of $request array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Okay, Here is the store method in my controller:

```
public function store(EmployeeRequest $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('photo')){
        $path = $request->photo->store('employeeimages');
// This should have changed the element in the $request['photo'] index:
        $request->photo = $path; 
    dd($request->all());
    }
    Employee::create($request->all());
    return redirect('dashboard');
}
```

I thought `$request->photo` gives us the access to the `$request['photo']` element of the array, so I tried to update it by `$request->photo = $path;` but when I die and dump `$request->all()`, `$request['photo']` is not updated and still holds a reference to the previous value, which is an instance of the `UploadedFile` class. How do I change an element of the $request array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the inputs to a new variable and then modifying it solves the issue. This is what I have done:

```
public function store(EmployeeRequest $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('photo')){
        $input = $request->all();
        $path = $request->photo->store('employeeimages');
        $input['photo'] = $path;
    }
    Employee::create($input);
    return redirect('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: You can use `$request->merge($array)` as well.